# Display columns as rows using jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Is there a way to display columns as rows? So that the number of rows represents the number of properties of the object we are trying to display and the number of columns is the number of records returned (in my case it is always one record).

Picture

[image]

I tried searching for an existing answer but haven't found one. I also tried using formatters but I guess they are only used to format a specified cell and not the whole table.

Comment: I find the question interesting, but we should specify the input data more clear. Let us you have input as array of objects which have simple properties (properties are not objects, but strings, Boolean or numbers). We need to generate `colModel` first of all. The number of columns will be the same as the number of elements in the input array. Then one have to build the grid data from the input data. On the other side if you need to display the properties of **one object** (you wrote about one record) then you can create really simple jqGrid, which do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you need to display enumerable properties of the object (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor)) and the values of the properties. The corresponding code could be for example the following:

```js
var myobject = {
    prop1: "value1",
    prop2: 2,
    prop3: new Date(),
    prop4: true,
    prop5: function () { return "Hello world!"; },
    prop6: null,
    prop7: { x: 1, y: 2, z: "some text"}
};
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    colModel: [
        { name: "name", width: 80 },
        { name: "type", width: 80 },
        { name: "value", width: 400 }
    ],
    datatype: "jsonstring",
    datastr: myobject,
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        root: function (obj) {
            var prop, result = [], value;
            for (prop in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    value = obj[prop];
                    result.push({
                        name: prop,
                        type: $.type(value),
                        value: $.type(value) === "object" ?
                                JSON.stringify(value) :
                                String(value)
                    });
                }
            }
            return result;
        },
    },
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    autoencode: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true },
    autoResizing: { compact: true },
    viewrecords: true,
    pager: true
});
```

The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/euau0yqj/2/ uses the code and displays the following results

[image]

The main logic of the demo is in `jsonReader.root`, which should return the array with the data. I used in the demo [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), the fork of jqGrid, which I develop since a year, but the main functionality should work with the old versions of jqGrid too.

Comment: Thank you very much Oleg for the time and effort you put into this! I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: I forgot to get back to you.. Just to let you know Oleg, your answer greatly helped to solve my issue. Thank you very much