# JQuery grid plugin to display grid columns vertically

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, datatables, kendo-grid

I need to display columns of UI grid vertically. For example, in a typical grid display, we represent data something like this:

```
    Name    Age      City
    ----    ---     -----
    John    35      New York
    Brian   37      London
    Tom     38      Phoenix
```

I need to display data as below:

```
    Name    John        Brian   Tom
    Age     35          37      38
    City    New York    London  Phoenix
```

I am looking a jQuery grid plug which can support this data format. I looked into Kendo Grid, JQGrid and DataTables but I didn't find any reliable solutions so far.

Comment: Can you include the test data in the text of your question? `jsonReader` with `root` property and `colModel` with `jsonmap` defined as functions can solve the problem. [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34639386/315935) provides an example of what you can do. In some other case (depend on format of input data) one need "preprocess" the input data to generate `colModel`.  It uses [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrid, which I develop since more as one year.